# Variance of binomial distribution with binomial distribution of $n$

Tags: binomial-distribution, variance

Accoring to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), the variance of a binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ is given by:

$Var(B(n,p)) = np(1-p)$

Now what is the variance of a bionomial distribution $B(n,p)$ where $n$ itself is defined by another binomial distribution $B(m,q)$?

In other words, what is $Var(B(B(m,q),p))$?

Comment: How would that work when a normal random variable can take non-integer or negative values?

Comment: Could it work if $n$ was defined by another binomial rather than a normal distribution?  In other words, what would be $Var(B(B(m,q),p))$?

Comment: NB: Question edited as per my last response.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the law of total variance:

$$ \text{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[\text{Var}(X \mid Y)] + \text{Var}[\mathbb E(X \mid Y)]$$

Comment: OK, so what would the total variance of $B(B(m,q),p)$ be in terms of $m$, $q$ and $p$?